# Cython throwing syntax error

Tags: python, c++, cython

Im learning cython and while trying to compile a program which has a simlpe statement like " int f = 9 " its throwing error.

cython test.pyx

```
int f=9
```

test.pyx:2:4: Syntax error in simple statement list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cdef int f = 9`

See [Typing Variables documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#typing-variables).